# How to multiply ints into list of lists

Tags: list, multiplication

I have list of lists -

list_1 = [[2,2],[3,4],[4,5],[2,1]

i want to multiply the list with
x = 2

output will be:

list_1 =[[4,4],[6,8],[8,10],[4,2]]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
list_1 = [[2,2],[3,4],[4,5],[2,1]]
x = 2

[[elem*x for elem in l] for l in list_1]
>>>
[[4, 4], [6, 8], [8, 10], [4, 2]]
```